# Not able to toggle on Firefox

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc-2, firefox

```
    <div>
    <%
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model)
        { %>
    <div class="row <%= item.IsEditable ? "" : "readonly"%> 
                    <%= index % 2 == 0 ? "row":"rowAlt" %>  
                    var cId = <%= item.Id %>
                    <%= item.IsEditable ? "onclick='page.toggleMe(cId)'":"" %>                        
        <span style="float: right;">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <%
        index++;
        } %>
</div>
```

The code above works on IE and toggles the row by passing cId. However, the same code doesn't work in Firefox. I think it is not able to recognize the way cId is being passed. 
I also tried:

<%= item.IsEditable ? "onclick='page.toggleMe(<%= item.Id %>)'":"" %>

but shows a syntax error. Any workarounds to get this working on FF?

Comment: Should the line `<%= item.IsEditable ? "onclick='page.toggleMe(cId)'":"" %>` actually be `<%= item.IsEditable ? "onclick='page.toggleMe(" + cId + ")'":"" %>`?

Comment: Also, post your javascript function for toggleMe().

Comment: Also note that your div tag isn't closed.

Comment: That looks a mess. It's not a good idea to mix html and asp in the same page. Thats why you have a code behind file.

Comment: What on the holy Earth is this tag soup? Does your views really look like this? If they do, you are doing it wrong (whatever you are doing) and there's a better way.

Comment: @Ivan: If I make that change, I get the error: the name 'cId' does not exist in the current context. The code in the toggleMe method just toggles the div based on some value:      div.toggleClass('excluded');
        div.toggleClass('selected');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll attempt to post a fix for this, but there are quite a few mistakes in the code you posted; likewise, the way you are going about this is very awkward to say the least.  Furthermore, I am unclear as to what your goal is.

```
<div>
    <%
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model)
        { %>
    <div class="row <%= item.IsEditable ? "" : "readonly"%> 
                    <%= index % 2 == 0 ? "row":"rowAlt" %>"
                    id="<%= item.Id %>" 
                    <%= item.IsEditable ? "onclick='page.toggleMe(this)'":"" %> >                    
        <span style="float: right;">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <%
        index++;
        } %>
</div>
```

Your toggleMe function should be changed to take the element instead of its id.

Comment: id="<%= item.Id %>" worked. Thanks for your help. I've inherited this messy code recently, trying to clean it up :)